# How to determine if the given points form a convex irregular Hexagon.

Tags: algorithms, convex-analysis, combinatorial-geometry

Say I have a collection of points (x,y). From the given points, I want to determine if it forms a convex irregular Hexagon.

My goal is to determine that the points I have gathered form an irregular Hexagon.  The given points may vary.  I can have as many as 60 - 80 or less paired values of (x,y) as my collection of points.  From there, I need to know if the collection of points formed an irregular Hexagon.

The 60-80 points for examples are my points. say the 1st point is at (10,11), 2nd is (11,12) and so on. so if I am going to graph the points I can tell if it forms an irregular Hexagon or not. But since I will not be graphing the points, so I need to look for a way without graphing the points that I can tell from the collection of points that it forms an irregular Hexagon (convex) or not .

Is that possible?

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by convex irregular hexagon? You have six points and want to know if none of them lie in the interior of their convex hull? If so, the easiest way I can think to do it is to compute the convex hull and check just that.

Comment: Yes, it certainly is possible. But you should indicate what you already know about this problem, so we don't expend unnecessary effort on definitions, etc. that you already know.

Comment: Updated hardmath

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by 60-80 points forming an irregular convex hexagon.

Comment: user753, the 60-80 points for examples are my points.  say the 1st point is at (10,11), 2nd is (11,12) and so on.  so if I am going to graph the points I can tell if it forms an irregular Hexagon or not.  But since I will not be graphing the points, so I need to look for a way without graphing the points that I can tell from the collection of points that it forms an irregular Hexagon (convex) or not .

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

Each six points form a hexagon (excluding some degenerated cases), but this hexagon may be non-convex. A polygon is convex iff each four vertices of it form a convex quadrilateral. May be four points form a convex quadrilateral iff them can be separated into to pairs, say $\{a,b\}$ and  $\{c,d\}$ such that segments $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ intersects in a their interior point.